# keyboard shortcut to scroll by word through linux command prompt command

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anybody out there know the linux keyboard shortcut for skipping words in a command prompt. 
 e.g.,

$ locate pdf | xargs -i ls -l {} | grep something

I'd like to scroll through the command by word by word rather than the default letter by letter.

Answer (score 4):

In bash you can use CTRL combined with the left and right arrows or ALT combined with F or B.

See [keyboard shortcuts](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/bash-shell-keyboard-shortcuts-default-command-shell-for-ubuntu.html), or [readline shortcuts](http://www.bigsmoke.us/readline/shortcuts).

Comment: Great links! Will make sure to file them away somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Zoredache's answer, you can find out the full list of keyboard shortcuts currently available for bash by issuing the command:

```
bind -P
```

Additionally, if you're more used to vi-style bindings than emacs-style, you can switch with:

```
set -o vi
```

and switch back with

```
set -o emacs
```

Answer (score 2):

On my macOS Catalina in both bash and zsh, scrolling by word is done with:

```
ALT + Arrow Left/Right
```